# Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) visibility issues with Ads on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, iframe, internet-explorer-11, ads, amp-html

Cube ads that are being displayed inside an iframe on IE11 are getting a visibility: hidden inline style added to it, which hides the ads. Does anyone know a workaround on this? This is not occurring on other acceptable browsers.

Comment: Could be a plugin disabling ads, like AdBlock. Do you have some code we can use to reproduce the problem? A jsFiddle / live demo would help.

Comment: Here are 3 sites that currently have this problem. Each one shows fine as AMP pages in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, & Edge, but if you open these pages in IE11, cube ads are invisible. Our company is having the same problem and we are triaging it now.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.washingtonpost.com/amphtml/blogs/plum-line/wp/2016/03/11/get-ready-donald-trump-youre-about-to-run-into-a-buzz-saw/#
https://www.google.com/amp/mobile.nytimes.com/2016/03/10/opinion/sanders-surprises.amp.html?client=safari#
https://www.google.com/amp/www.people.com/people/article/amp/0,,20993119,00.html?client=safari#

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug.  Have you reported it to the AMP Project on their GitHub page?

Comment: I haven't yet, that was my next step. Thanks Jordan.